# rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) with aliased columns on mysql

Tags: mysql, java, metadata

when I have a query result for something like:

```
select col as newName from table;
```

and I then do (in java) :

```
rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)
```

it returns the name of the column instead of "newName"...

if however I do

```
select concat(col,'') as newName from table;
```

it returns the expected "newName"

is there a way to get the "newName" without messing with tho sql query?

This is all mysql, java, tomcat 6.

Comment: This really isn't a sysadmin question, it's a programming question.  Voted to move.

Comment: sorry, did not intend to place this at serverfault to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `getColumnLabel()` instead:

```
rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i);
```

FYI, I did a test and `rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)` worked for me - ie it gave me the *alias*, not the column name, but perhaps you are using an older version of the JDBC driver and/or mysql database.

Comment: for me getColumnName only worked when the alias was on an expression. e.e. `select concat(field,'') as alias from table` did return the alias but `select field as alias from table` returned the original name.